# How do I sort in solr by term frequency in multiple fields?

Tags: solr

I have been assigned a task that I should change our solr search to sort a list returned by solr by using the term frequency.

Well, I´ve found a way to do so simply by using `omitNorms="true"`.

The problem is, that this won´t work when I am doing a field - search, say by name:

```
q=name:jones
```

Following this example I get a list of document whose term frequency is the highest for the "name" field. But What I wanted to achieve is to have a query that is giving my a list of documents whose term frequency is the highest for ALL fields.

Example: If a User named Jones also has the word "Jones" in his biography 10 times I want that document ranked higher.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search for the query word in all fields and use the fielded query as a filter.  Assuming that Solr is setup to search all fields by default, your query should be `q=jones&fq=name:jones`